# UINavigationBar Weird Standard Height

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar

I am confused when I see my app's UINavigationBar's height. It seems to be taller than other apps and the size of it's Status Bar font is bigger than other apps

Please take a look at the screenshots below. I did not do anything to my app's NavigationBar.

What could possibly caused this?

Thoughts??

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing those screen shots are on an iPhone 6. So evidently *your* app is not iPhone 6 native. Therefore it is portrayed as an iPhone 5 app, zoomed - hence larger.

This is a pity because you are not getting all the pixels you are entitled to (and also I believe it won't get past the gatekeepers at the App Store).

Comment: How do I set it to "iPhone 6 native" though? Really confused

Comment: I mean if you revised it today it wouldn't get on the store. I could be wrong of course

Comment: So what could I do to fix this? any idea? Searched everywhere and you are the only one pointing this out

Comment: Use correct launch image or nib.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of a long-shot But conform to the UINavigationBarDelegate and try implementing this method

```
- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar {
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```

The greater likelihood is that it is scaling to fit a 6 / 6+ in which case you need to add the proper launch image assets.